# ¿Cómo puedo solucionar un conflicto de css entre AOS y un preloader?

Tags: javascript, html5, css3, scroll, animated

estoy rediseñando mi [sitio web](https://test.elgatodiego.com/) e implemente un cargador que encontré en [codepen](https://codepen.io/zerospree/pen/aCjAz), pero veo que está interfiriendo con la librería de [Animate On Scroll](https://michalsnik.github.io/aos/) Ya que el logo de la página y algunos elementos no se muestran, al hacer el scroll hacia arriba o hacia abajo los elementos no se muestran correctamente.

Estos son los estilos para el cargador:

```
.load{position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
    /*change these sizes to fit into your project*/
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
  }
  .load hr{border:0;margin:0;width:40%;height:40%;position:absolute;border-radius:50%;animation:spin 2s ease infinite}
  
  .load :first-child{background:#19A68C;animation-delay:-1.5s}
  .load :nth-child(2){background:#F63D3A;animation-delay:-1s}
  .load :nth-child(3){background:#FDA543;animation-delay:-0.5s}
  .load :last-child{background:#193B48}
  
  @keyframes spin{
    0%,100%{transform:translate(0)}
    25%{transform:translate(160%)}
    50%{transform:translate(160%, 160%)}
    75%{transform:translate(0, 160%)}
  }
```

Y este es el script para el cargador:

```
window.onload=function(){
    $('#onload').fadeOut();
}
```

Si quito del código el elemento **data-aos="fade-down"** las imágenes se muestran, pero sin la animación

¿Hay alguna forma de detectar donde está el conflicto? Ó ¿Cómo Solucionarlo?

MUCHAS GRACIAS

Comment: Crea un pen en codepen para poder detectar el problema

Comment: Hola, te envio el link del pen y  tambien el arcivo.zip https://codepen.io/gatocode2016/pen/gOPvojo - 
https://test.elgatodiego.com/conflicto-cargador-aos.zip GRACIAS

Comment: Te recomiendo que descargues el zip